# How to display items from database one by one each time a submit is clicked in php

Tags: javascript, php

Well, I'm having a page where I wanna display the items stored in the database one by one. One by one means on click of a button the next item should come. (Items are the questions by the way in my case).

So I wrote the code for this. The problem I'm getting is that the loop is working only one time. I mean when the next button is clicked, I'm getting the next item displayed, but then I click Next again 'n nothing happens. Here's the code..

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("qus", $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $sd = $_SESSION['qs'] = 1;
    if (isset($_REQUEST['next']))
    {
        $sd = $_SESSION['qs'] + 1;
    }

    if (isset($_REQUEST['prev']))
    {
        if (sd == -1)
        {
            $message = "No Question Available";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['qs']--;
    }

    $query = mysql_query("select * from qustion where id='$sd'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $ques = $row['qust'];
        $op1  = $row['op1'];
        $op2  = $row['op2'];
        $op3  = $row['op3'];
        $op4  = $row['op4'];
        $ans  = $row['ans'];
    }
?><body>
    <form action="" method="POST"><h1><?php
echo $ques;
?></h1><br>
        <input type="radio" name="op1"><?php
echo $op1;
?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="op2"><?php
echo $op2;
?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="op3"><?php
echo $op3;
?><br>
        <input type="radio" name="op4"><?php
echo $op4;
?><br>
        <input type="submit" name="next" value="next" id="next">
        <input type="submit" name="prev" value="previous" id="prev">
    </form>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code.

Comment: You seem to be looking for pagination in PHP am I correct in assuming this?

Comment: You are setting `$_SESSION['qs']` to `1` on **every** page load. That means that every time you click `next` you'll get `2` for the variable `$sd`. Also, check your typos, you **might** get an error if your code has `if (sd == -1)` when it's supposed to be `if ($sd == -1)`

Comment: there is no error in this code but its showing only two values from database means $sd=2 later its not getting incremented what to do??

Answer (score 0):

Hi please have a look at the following post and tutorial for pagination in php hope this helps. [Paginate data with PHP](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-data-with-php--net-2928)